# Which typewriter font fits to Linux Libertine and supports bold letters?

Tags: fonts, typography, bold, typewriter, libertine

I'm thinking about using the Linux Libertine font (`\usepackage{libertine}`) in my next TeX documents.  For listings with syntax highlighting I will need a typewriter font that supports boldface.

I used to use Courier (`\usepackage{courier}`), but a big disadvantage is, that the Courier font clashes with Linux Libertine.

So my question is: Is there typewriter font, supporting boldface, that does not clash with the Linux Libertine font?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Open Type Version of Libertine has also a typewriter version. However, for `pdflatex` you can use the Bera Mono:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[scaled=0.83]{beramono}

\begin{document}
This is a test with \texttt{some \textbf{bold} typewriter text}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want Bera Mono for LuaTeX or XeTeX then use

```
\setmonofont[Scale=0.83]{Bitstream Vera Sans Mono}
```

The TrueType font is available from http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/ttf-bitstream-vera/1.10/ 
A survey of monotype fonts is here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30040/Font-Survey-42-of-the-Best-Monospaced-Programming

Answer (score 16):

Inconsolata fits well with Linux Libertine, and has a bold face:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setmonofont{Inconsolata}

\begin{document}

This is a test with \texttt{some \textbf{bold} typewriter text}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This can also (as of TeXLive 2015) be evoked by loading `\usepackage[scaled=0.96]{zi4}`, following `\usepackage{libertine}`.  (Disclaimer: the scale factor there is my own best attempt to match their x-heights; I’m not an expert.)