# Libertine monospaced font seems to big

Tags: typewriter, libertine

I'd like to write a document with the Libertine font (using the `libertine` package). I have a couple of code snippets in the text, and to me it seems like the Libertine Mono font that is used by the package is too large compared to the rest of the text (notice the 'x'-height):

[image]

compared to the same snippet using Computer Modern:

[image]

Is there something wrong with my setup, or is that just the way Libertine Mono is supposed to look? If that's the case, is there a way to automatically use a slightly smaller text size for all monospaced output (`\texttt`, `\verb`, listings...)?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
abc \texttt{abc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can scale it using a package option: `\usepackage[ttscale=.875]{libertine}`

Comment: Personally, I don't like this this monospace (in my opinion it looks bad), it is not like other teletypes, it has serifs and more. I think your document will look better with other monospaced font (i.e., `luximono` package or `txtt` font). Just a suggestion, the answer is in cgnieder comment.

Comment: @Manuel It's not distinguishable from the Roman type, particularly if scaled down, so it doesn't do its job. And I agree it's not the best member of the Libertine family. ;-)

Comment: @cgnieder: Thanks, that works (should have read the documentation, sorry). Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Manuel and egreg: Good point, it's really not a very monospaced font. LuxiMono and TXTT both seem nice, thanks for the suggestion. It seems like LuxiMono is not in TeXLive?

Comment: No, it isn't. You can install `luximono` trough [`getnonfreefonts`](http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) script. By the way, you can look at [the font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html) to choose one. `inconsolata` is also good (at this moment I can't try if it looks good with libertine).

Comment: @Manuel: Sweet, that worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @Jake well, it is _monospaced_ but doesn't look very teletype-like... I don't like it either.

Comment: @cgnieder: Sorry, I meant "not a very *good* monospaced font"...

Comment: I settled for Xe/LuaLaTeX and `\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{DejaVu Sans Mono}` (provided by the `dejavu` package) to complement Linux Libertine.

Comment: For everyone else who doesn’t like the standard libertine monospace font much, a couple of options (not needing Xe/LuaLaTeX) are given at the question [Which typewriter font fits to Linux Libertine and supports bold letters?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71340)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It can be scaled using a package option `\usepackage[ttscale=.875]{libertine}` (you need to play with the value a bit, this is just an initial guess):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ttscale=.875]{libertine}

\begin{document}
some text \texttt{monospaced} and normal text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you were using XeLaTeX, `Scale=MatchLowercase` might be an option, too. (It would probably have to go somewhere else though, not in an option to the package.)

Comment: @doncherry yes, that should do (via a `fontspec` command) I would think